# When using a secondary monitor with Windows 10 gaming PC, the computer freezes when waking from sleep

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, freeze, sleep

I recently got a secondary monitor for my PC and when using both monitors with Windows 10 gaming PC, the computer freezes when waking from sleep after locking with Windows + L (after about 15 minutes of being left alone and locked).

When the issue has happened, it is the secondary monitor that is frozen on the lock screen and the mouse cursor is stuck in the exact centre of the screen. The PC does not respond to:

- Mouse clicks
- Keyboard presses
- Ctrl + Alt + Delete

The only way to get the PC working again is to hard reset by holding then power button.

I have tried to replicate this with only one monitor connected, and the issue does not happen, so my assumption at the moment is something is breaking or crashing because I have two monitors connected.

### Things I have tried:

- Updating Nvidia drivers and Windows updates
- Changing cables/ports used
- Event Viewer has no critical errors at the time of the freeze
- Checked for BIOS updates

### Specs and monitors

- PC: Alienware Aurora R9
- OS: Windows 10 Home 64-bit, Version 20H2, OS Build 19042.685
- CPU: i9-9900K
- GPU: Nvidia RTX 2080 Ti
- 2x 16GB PC4-19200 DDR4 SDRAM Kingston XRMWRN-MIE
- SSD: Micron 2200S NVMe 1TB
- HDD: Toshiba DT01ACA100 1TB
- Monitor 1: LG 27GN950-B connected via DisplayPort
- Monitor 2 (newly added monitor): LG 27GL63T connected via DisplayPort

Let me know if any further details are needed.

If anyone has any suggestions of how to further troubleshoot this or things to try to fix the problem, it is much appreciated, thanks!

**UPDATE**: I have changed my Windows power settings to not make the PC sleep or turn the display off after a certain amount of time, and this obviously prevents this issue from happening. This is certainly a workaround, but I am fine with the PC not sleeping when locked so for all purposes this has fixed the issue. If anyone does know what causes this issue though, I'm still curious to know.

Comment: Anything in event viewer around the times it happens?

Answer (score 0):

Check for any available driver updates, to begin with. Alternatively, the monitor has a fault of some sort.

I'd plug the monitor into a different computer and see how that other computer behaves, or I'd plug the secondary monitor to your primary graphics port and observe the same.

And then I'd throw that monitor away. It is HIGHLY likely that whatever relatively minor faults you've having right now are merely symptoms of the deeper damage your secondary monitor is doing to your system.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 


I have checked for driver updates for both the monitor and GPU and there aren't any available.


Unfortunately I don't have a secondary computer to try the monitor with so can't test this out.


I'm curious what damage you think the monitor could be causing? It's brand new and functions absolutely fine other than when waking up my PC from sleep. If I change my Windows settings to make the PC not sleep, the issue no longer happens which makes me think its a bug in either Windows or the GPU drivers once the PC is woken up from sleep.

Comment: Then the issue is with drivers. Drivers are the most common cause of problems with sleep.